# Error Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. How can I DataBind after selected value on CheckListbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, checklistbox

I have the following code to select either the next list item or the first list item in CheckListBox:

```
        var calculateRate = cancellation.CancellationCalculateRates;
        foreach (ListItem item in chkListRate.Items)
        {
            chkListRate.DataBind(); >>> Error Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
            var cancel = ConverterHelper.To<int>(item.Value);
            item.Selected = calculateRate.Any(i => i.CancellationId.Equals(cancel));
        }
```

How can I DataBind after selected value on CheckListbox?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you cannot modify a collection during enumeration(`foreach`). So deleting and inserting is not allowed. `CheckBoxList.DataBind` is modifying it therefore the error.

But it's not clear what you are actually trying to do. You are databinding the list on every item which seems to be pointless, isn't it? So my sugestion is to remove the `chkListRate.DataBind();` from the loop:

```
foreach (ListItem item in chkListRate.Items)
{
    var cancel = ConverterHelper.To<int>(item.Value);
    item.Selected = calculateRate.Any(i => i.CancellationId.Equals(cancel));
}
```